# Generating Random Constrained Graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, graph

I need to generate a randomized graph with a fixed number of vertices. I'm having some difficulty getting a solution every time.

*Graph Rules*

1. Each Vertex will have a random number of connections that is at most N-1 where N is the total number of vertices.
2. The Vertices cannot contain direct connections to themselves
3. The vertices cannot contain duplicate connections to other vertices.
4. If a vertex A is connected to Vertex B then Vertex B must connect to Vertex A.
5. Each vertex must connect to at least 3 other vertices. So each vertex will have between [3,N-1] edges.

I'm getting a correct solution about 70% of the time, but other times I get fairly far into the graph then no valid vertices are left. What constraints on the vertex connections do I need to guarantee a solution?

**What I'm doing so far**

1. Randomize a number of connections for each vertex between [3,N-1].
2. Check that the total number of connections is even. If A points to B and B points to A then the total number of connections in the graph should be even or else there is no solution. If it is odd modify a vertex so the total number is even.
3. Fill in each vertex that is fully constrained. So a vertex that has N-1 connections must point to ALL other vertices. Fill in a connection from that vertex to all others and give all other vertices a connection to the fully constrained ones.
4. Process each vertex by how tightly it is constrained. So process all vertices with N-2 connections then, N-3 connection, then N-4, etc by generated random vertex indexes.
5. If The new random index is valid connect them then continue, if it is not valid rerandom the index until you get a valid value. (The graphs are only going to be 7-15 nodes or so maximum so this doesn't take extremely long).

Generally I get to the last 2 vertices but then have no valid values left with this method. Each needs 1 more connection but they are already connected to each other. Anyone have a better algorithm or an additional constraint on the number of connections values that would help me out?

There should BE many solutions given there is an even number of edges, but my algorithm above obviously doesn't guarantee that one will be found.

Comment: "*The graph cannot contain direct connections to itself*". You probably wanted to say the *vertex* cannot contain a direct connection to itself?

Comment: Edited, oops. Yes, Vertices cannot have loops that directly connect them to themselves. However, there are no issues if 2 connections down the line there is a loop made of 3 or more vertices.

Comment: I do not understand how you can run out of valid connections on the last 1 or 2 vertices, since your requirements allow connections to every other vertex?  The need to pair connections doesn't seem to create a problem, since you can add both directions at the same time (or structure the data to imply both directions with one data point).  There is no way to run out of valid values.  Are there constraints that you haven't listed, such as how you choose whether a vertex will have N-2, N-3, N-4, etc connections; or, is there a constraint that requires a path to all vertices?

Comment: As for 4th list item, do you mean direct connections (edged) or connections via other vertices (routes)? How dense should your graph be; what are numbers of vertices and edges? Do you have constraints on connectivity number?

Comment: Matt: When I add a connection to A I also add it to B so they both know there is a connection between the two. The issue is when I get to the lowest level it is for some reason possible that sometimes all vertices are full or connected to already connected to the one that still has open connections. So when it fails I normally have 2 vertices that have 1 open connection each, but they are already connected together so they are no longer valid connections.

Comment: George: I forgot to mention each vertex must connect to at least 3 other vertices. So between [3,N-1] undirected edges between each vertex. That is now added to the problem solution.

No other restrictions are on the number of edges each vertex has other then that they need to be random in the range [3,N-1]. There should be a large number of possible solutions. I just need an algorithm that guarantees that I find one.

Comment: Are the node degrees given to you as an input?

Comment: No they also need to be random between [3,N-1]. The only input is the number of vertices N. N is guaranteed to be greater than 3.

Comment: One option to consider would be to rejection sample by just repeatedly generating random graphs where each edge exists with probability 50% and checking to see if each node has enough edges. That'll produce a uniform distribution over valid graphs, and with a minimum degree of only 3, it shouldn't take a prohibitively large number of tries.

Comment: How many edges are you trying to generate for a graph of `n` vertices?

Comment: @MattJordan is right: None of the decisions you make early on ever *remove* valid possible edges later.  If a graph has at least 4 vertices then it can always be solved by repeatedly looking for a vertex with at most 2 outgoing edges, then randomly picking however many additional neighbouring vertices it needs, and adding new edges in each direction.  If your code gets stuck, then it has a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a vector of all vertices with fewer than 3 edges.
2. Choose a vertex from the vector at random.
3. Copy the vector with the chosen vertex removed (you could swap the chosen vertext and the last one and adjust the size).
4. Also remove all target vertices already connected to the chosen vertex.
5. Choose a vertex from the copied vector, and create an edge in each direction between the two chose n vertices
6. Repeat steps 1..5 as long as the vector of all vertices with fewer than 3 edges is not empty